# Reflection Invoke With Parameters c# Error

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection

I get this error

> 'System.Reflection.TargetException', The object does not match target
>   type.

### This is my Class

```
public clas Service 
{
  public DataTable ArticlesGet(string SearchValue = null, string SearchColumn = null, string SearchOperator = "%")
  {

    //Methods Here
  }
}
```

---

### This is my Reflection Code

```
object obj = new Service();
Type Type = obj.GetType();
MethodInfo MethodInfo = Type.GetMethod("ArticlesGet");
MethodInfo.Invoke(Type, new object[] { "", "", "%" });  // Error
```

Thank You in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't name your variable `Type`

Comment: could you give any example or something better than?

Comment: Even `serviceType` is better, at all will avoid conflicts. Btw. you might try `typeof(Service)` as first parameter instead.

Comment: you are naming your variable the same as a the class Type its the same as doing string string;

Comment: You have to provide an instance of Service, invocation syntax you are using is for static methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the instance on which you want to invoke that method, not its type:

```
DataTable table = (DataTable) MethodInfo.Invoke(obj, new object[] { "", "", "%" });
```

Comment: thank you very much !! worked perfect !! you saved me a lot of time! Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Try this simple way, it's simple and clear code:

```
   Type ty = typeof(Service);
   Service myTypeObject = (Service)Activator.CreateInstance(ty);

    DataTable myDataTable = myTypeObject.ArticlesGet("SearchValue", "SearchColumn", "SearchOperator");
```

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to `Method.Invoke` is the instance of the object, which should be `obj` in your case, not `Type`

Answer (score 1):

Just you need to fix the line No 4 where you invoke your method, you need to pass the object instance instead of passing class Type object.

```
object obj = new Service();
Type Type = obj.GetType();
MethodInfo MethodInfo = Type.GetMethod("ArticlesGet");
var dataTableObject = MethodInfo.Invoke(obj, new object[] { "", "", "%" });
```